# Computing angular velocity on a different point of body

Tags: rotational-dynamics, reference-frames, rigid-body-dynamics, angular-velocity

Suppose you have a rigid body and you have two local coordinate systems on the body at $P_1$ and $P_2$ and we can write a vector in the $P_2$ coordinate system using $P_1$ via the transformation $v_{p2} = R*v_{p1} + T$.

We know the instantaneous angular velocity vector of the object written with respect to $P_1$, how do we compute the angular velocity vector respect to $P_2$? Additionally how do we compute the orientation of the object with respect to $P_2$ assuming we know its orientation with respect to $P_1$? In other words suppose we know euler angles $(\alpha, \beta, \gamma )$ to rotate the object into the reference frame $P_1$ from a coordinate system located at $P_1$ which is parallel to the global coordinate system and we want to know the euler angles to transform the coordinate system at $P_2$ parallel to the global coordinate system to orient the object the same as it is oriented in $P_1$.

Comment: Angular and tangential accelerations are related like : $$\alpha ={\frac {a_{\perp }}{r}}.$$ So having one, you will deduce the other.

Comment: I should have written angular velocity, but basically I have a gyro and I want to compute the orientation on the body using another coordinate frame attached to the body.

Comment: Please state your problem better. What kind of body? magnitude and-or  direction of angular velocity? what is " the orientation on the body "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two coordinate systems have different orientations, and $R$ is the rotation matrix going from one to the other, then the angular velocity vector is simply transformed as

$$ \omega_{\rm p2} = R\; \omega_{\rm p1}$$

Angular velocity *is not* location dependent, as it is shared by the entire body and you are just expressing the same quantity in different basis-vectors. The location of the two coordinate systems (and the associated translation $T$) plays no role here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this, wouldn't the angular velocity be different since you're adding in a translation also? I mean if you rotate the object based upon the angular velocity around two different points you get two different orientations don't you?

Comment: No, you do not. Take a horizontal body and rotate by 30° from one end or the other end. In both situations, the _orientation_ of the body will be the same, 30° from horizontal. A rigid body has a singular angular velocity quantity that can be expressed along different orientations with different vector components, but all cases represent the _same_ rotational velocity.

Comment: So if we integrate the same angular velocity from any point on the object the final orientation would be the same?

Comment: ".. angular velocity from any point on the object" - As I said, angular velocity is not location specific. Regardless of _where_ you mount a MEMS gyro, the measurement will be the same. So yes.